# Changing neutral value from 0 to different number. | reract-chartjs-2

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2, chartjs-2.6.0

I´m trying to implement a Bar Chart with react-chartjs-2 in a web app.
It is possible to make a graph where values above zero head up and values below zero head down.
So far so good. But now i need to set the neutral value to 3 instead of 0. Does anyone know if this is possible? And if yes, how? Fill seems to only work for Area Charts.
Thanks in advance!

Searched the docus of Chartjs and react-chartjs-2 but counldn´t find anything helpful

Comment: You probably want to set the [`base`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general) value